# JPA mixing nullable and not nullable join columns

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join, jpql

I've got a problem in which my db consists of two tables `A,B`. Table `B's` primary key contains columns `C,D` and `A` has reference to `B` (via columns `E,F`). I want to have one column `E` in `A` be nullable and column `F` not nullable. Although, JPA throws following exception:.

```
"Mixing nullable and non nullable columns"
```

How do I fix this problem? thanks.

Comment: Please post your entities here.

Answer (score 0):

table A cannot refer to table B when `C, D` are the primary keys, while table A is trying to refer from different columns (`E, F`).
You should change your logic. Table `A's` foreign keys must point to Table `B's` primary keys.
Candidate keys must not be null, and they must be unique all together.